# adding jquery.min.js file to phonegap eclipse application

Tags: eclipse, jquery-mobile, cordova, eclipse-plugin

i am using jquery for first time in a phonegap eclipse application.i have downloaded jquery.min.js file from internet.now i want to include that file into my project folder .so please help me how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if u are using eclipse than do one thing,every time including jquery for every new project is not a smart task,i am giving u one link by which u will be able to install phonegap plugin in eclipse,so after following that u will get such symbol as given in below image.after clicking on that symbol u will be able to create phonegap project directly from that,and project will automatically include all jquery min js,phonegap.js etc files required for creating phonegap environment.here is a  image[image]

and here is a link u need to follow for installing phonegap plugin in eclipse

follow all steps given on than have a look at this link

http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start

http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/startdetails

best of luck

Aamirkhan I.

Comment: i used it but its loading html,css.js files but not j query

Comment: yeah thans i was forgetting to ckeck include available jquery file..thanks.by the way.

Comment: Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'JavaScript Validator' on project 'hi'.
9

Comment: can i get ur e mal id for any help

Comment: sure see my profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/1042889/aamirpathan here i have put email address

Comment: i installed eclipse freshly and updated adt,sdk and phonegap but still im getting workspace build error..