# Phone gap application for Android on Eclipse

Tags: android, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adding jquery.min.js file to phonegap eclipse application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184654/adding-jquery-min-js-file-to-phonegap-eclipse-application)

I have been trying to setup and run my first Phone Gap application with Eclipse. This is the tutorial i am following ( http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap-Eclipse-PlugIn-for-Android ). But it does not seem to work. Nothing happens when i launch the app and below is the console output

```
[2012-06-28 16:14:05 - MyProjectName] ------------------------------

[2012-06-28 16:14:05 - MyProjectName] Android Launch!

[2012-06-28 16:14:05 - MyProjectName] adb is running normally.

[2012-06-28 16:14:05 - MyProjectName] No Launcher activity found!

[2012-06-28 16:14:05 - MyProjectName] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

[2012-06-28 16:14:05 - MyProjectName] Performing sync

[2012-06-28 16:14:05 - MyProjectName] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'AVD15'

[2012-06-28 16:14:08 - MyProjectName] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.

[2012-06-28 16:14:08 - MyProjectName] \MyProjectName\bin\MyProjectName.apk installed on device

[2012-06-28 16:14:08 - MyProjectName] Done!
```

EDITED : The files and console after checking the 'Create Activity' check box as advice by Rajesh

Activity.java

```
package my.com.phonegap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyPhonePrjActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

Manifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.com.phonegap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyPhonePrjActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Console Output

```
[2012-06-28 17:54:26 - MyPhonePrj] ------------------------------
[2012-06-28 17:54:26 - MyPhonePrj] Android Launch!
[2012-06-28 17:54:26 - MyPhonePrj] adb is running normally.
[2012-06-28 17:54:26 - MyPhonePrj] Performing my.com.phonegap.MyPhonePrjActivity activity launch
[2012-06-28 17:54:26 - MyPhonePrj] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD15'
[2012-06-28 17:54:26 - MyPhonePrj] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD15'
[2012-06-28 17:54:39 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2012-06-28 17:54:39 - Emulator] 
[2012-06-28 17:54:39 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-06-28 17:54:39 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-06-28 17:54:47 - Emulator] NAND: nand_dev_load_disk_state ftruncate failed: Invalid argument
[2012-06-28 17:54:47 - Emulator] savevm: unable to load section nand_dev
[2012-06-28 18:01:23 - HelloAndroid] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-06-28 18:01:23 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-06-28 18:01:23 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2012-06-28 18:03:34 - HelloAndroid] Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-06-28 18:03:34 - HelloAndroid] (null)
[2012-06-28 18:03:35 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 1):

Your project does not seem to have a launcher activity.  This can happen if you did not create an activity while creating the project - may be you forgot to check the "**Create Activity**" checkbox. Please verify that you are creating the activity.

If that doesn't work, update your question with the code for your activity as well as the contents of the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: You are right i forgot to check the 'Create Activity' checkbox. It progresses and shows me the emulator but no output. Please see the edits i have made in the question

Comment: This time, the AVD seems have an issue. Delete and re-create the AVD and try again.

Answer (score 1):

That wiki is probably out of date. Follow this url for instructions on setting up your first app on Android:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android